# How to pass data from all WebGrid rows to MVC controller using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, model-view-controller, webgrid

I'm trying to pass data from my WebGrid(see image below) into my Controller using Javascript.

[image]

Currently I'm stuck at iterating through my WebGrid and obtaining each rows its value. With the code below I'm getting 4 empty alerts(I think its rows of my WebGrid including header).

What I've got so far:

**HTML**

```
@{
                if (Model != null && Model.Count() > 0)
                {
                    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 10);
                    grid.Bind(source: Model, rowCount: 0, autoSortAndPage: false);

                    <div class="row" id="content2">
                        <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex align-items-stretch">

                            @grid.Table(tableStyle: "table table-responsive table-striped table-bordered",
                                htmlAttributes: new { id = "tableID" },
                                columns: grid.Columns(
                                grid.Column(columnName: "A", header: "A", format:@<text><div class="" data-id="@item.KeyA" data-propertyname="KeyA">@item.KeyA</div></text>),
                                grid.Column("Other", header: "Other", format: @<text>@Html.DropDownList("OtherKey", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.OtherKeysList, new { @class = "extra-class" })</text>)))
                        </div>
                        <!--Pagerlist for webgrid-->
                        <div class="col-lg-12 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                            @grid.PagerList(mode: WebGridPagerModes.All, paginationStyle: "pagination pagination-small pagination-right")
                        </div>

                        @Html.Hidden("dir", grid.SortDirection)
                        @Html.Hidden("col", grid.SortColumn)
                    </div>
                }
}
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

       var dict = [];

       $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
           $('#tableID tr').each(function () {
               alert($(this));
               //Obtain row data and and push into "dict"
           });
       });

</script>
```

**Generated WebGrid**

[image]

Hope someone can help me out,

thanks in advance!

Comment: What are you stuck with? Do you get the alert? Do you see/not see the row? Are you unable to access the table cells?

Comment: I'm getting the alert 4 times, I think its all 4 rows of my WebGrid including header. I dont know how to extract the different values of this row("A" and "Other") so I can add them to my dictionary.

Comment: It will be helpful if you share the html generated the html generated by @grid.table helper

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I've updated the content, is this what you mean?

Comment: @NielsStenden Yes and now which data values you want to fetch?

Comment: @MohsinMehmood thet text "key1" from column "KeyA" and the selected value of the DropDownList of column "OtherKey", so: "otherkey1", "otherkey2" or "otherkey3".

Comment: In your example, `this` will give you your table row.  Here's just one of many examples (searching for 'table row dom') on [accessing table children in the dom](http://www.javascripthive.info/javascript/access-tables-row-and-cell-using-javascript/).